# jQuery appendTo problem on IE

Tags: jquery

The code below works fine on Firefox, Safari etc with no errors at all. But won't work on any IE, also reports errors. Can someone help please?

HTML

```
<p class="tooltip-ent">...</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('<span class="tt-icon-ent">Something</span>').appendTo('.tooltip-ent');
$('<span class="tt-popup-ent">PopupContent</span>').appendTo('.tt-icon-ent');
$('.tt-icon-ent').mouseover(function() { $('.tt-popup-ent', this).addClass('tt-popup-show'); });
$('.tt-icon-ent').mouseout(function() { $('.tt-popup-ent', this).removeClass('tt-popup-show'); });
```

CSS

for "tt-popup-show" basically display block and position absolute

Comment: sorry it's just here and fixed, it's correct in the real html code.

Comment: the error is "doesn't support this property or method"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this:

```
$('<span/>', {'class': 'tt-icon-ent'})
    .append(
        $('<img/>', {src: 'media/img/icon_ent_small_dark.png'})
    )
    .appendTo('tooltip-ent');
```

Comment: no problem on firefox, but won't work on IE the error: Message: Expected identifier, string or number

Comment: @Ray Try now -- I forgot `class` was a reserved word.

Comment: I changed the 2nd span tt-popup-ent to the above format as well. then i think it's working now. thank you!

Comment: one more question,you see my code the i have a span with in a span how can i do that please?

Comment: $('<span class="tt-popup-ent"><span class="text">This feature is<br /> available in our<br /> Enterprise Editions.</span><span class="link"><a href="#">See all Features</span></span>').appendTo('.tt-icon-ent');

Comment: just attached the code above,could you help to convert to your example format please?

Comment: @Ray You probably don't need to. Closing that last `a` tag should be enough. (The format above would be rather clunky for this string...)

Comment: OH, all the problem is because of the missing </a>. why IE get so confused!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works cross browser for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('.tooltip-ent').append('<span class="tt-icon-ent"><img src="media/img/icon_ent_small_dark.png" /></span>');

                $('.tt-icon-ent').append('<span class="tt-popup-ent"><span class="link"><a href="#">See all Features</span></span><span class="text">This feature is<br /> available in our<br /> Enterprise Editions.</span>');


                $('.tt-icon-ent').mouseover(function() { $('.tt-popup-ent', this).addClass('tt-popup-show'); });
                $('.tt-icon-ent').mouseout(function() { $('.tt-popup-ent', this).removeClass('tt-popup-show'); });


            });
```

Change your `$('.tt-icon-ent').mouseover(function()` bits to: `$('.tt-icon-ent').live('hover', function() {`

...and make sure it is *outside* of your `$(document).ready()` that should delegate a live hover function to your dynamically appended elements :)

Comment: still no rollover popup, OK i'm going to do the image as inline content, should be easier. thanks for your help!